# Why custom dialog box button is not working in android

Tags: android, dialog

We have creating two custom dialog box, one is about and another one is alert. When i choose alternately in the tow custom dialog box at that time the button is not working.

Sample code

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
Context mContext;
LayoutInflater inflater;
View layout;
Dialog dialog;
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog( int id ) 
{ 
    switch ( id ) 
    {
        case 1:
            builder = null;
            mContext = this;
            inflater = ( LayoutInflater ) mContext.getSystemService( LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            layout = inflater.inflate( R.layout.alert_page, ( ViewGroup ) findViewById( R.id.alert_Root ) );
            Button alertUser = ( Button ) layout.findViewById( R.id.alert_Submit );
            alertUser.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick( View v )
                {
                    try
                    {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    catch ( Exception e ) 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText( getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( mContext );
            builder.setView( layout );
            dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            break;

        case 2:
            builder = null;
            mContext = this;
            inflater = ( LayoutInflater ) mContext.getSystemService( LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            layout = inflater.inflate( R.layout.about_page, ( ViewGroup ) findViewById( R.id.about_Root ) );
            Button aboutUser = ( Button ) layout.findViewById( R.id.about_Submit );
            aboutUser.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick( View v )
                {
                    Log.e("About","About");
                    try
                    {
                        Log.e("About1","About");
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    catch ( Exception e ) 
                    {
                        Log.e("About","About12");
                        Toast.makeText( getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( mContext );
            builder.setView( layout );
            dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            break;
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

For example i am using two button. First button is called `case 1` and second button is called `case 2`.

I am selected First button to access `case 1` and then selected custom dialog box `alertUser` button `successfully Exit the dialog box`.

Immediately I am selected Second button to access `case 2` and then select custom dialog box `aboutUser` button `successfully Exit the dialog box`.

After Immediately I am selected First button to access `case 1` and then select custom dialog box `alertUser` button `Now the dialog box does not exist (button is now not working)`.

Where i am mistaken code. How do solved this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of layout = inflater.inflate( R.layout.alert_page, ( ViewGroup ) findViewById( R.id.alert_Root ) ); write layout = inflater.inflate( R.layout.alert_page, null );

Comment: you are calling dialog as `showDialog(int)` ? Then why you are writing this line `dialog.show();` in `onCreateDialog`

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem I can remove this line `dialog.show();` after i got same problem.

Comment: remove it..and call `dismissDialog(int)` to dismiss the dialog instead of `dialog.dismiss();
`

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem Thanks. It's working fine. Please explain why my old code is not working when i use `dialog.dismiss();`

Comment: May be it is due to the wrong reference of the dialog..as you have same reference for both dialogs..but I am not shur. And also I am posting this as answer so other can get help..and me also you know..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are calling dialog as `showDialog(int)`. remove this line `dialog.show();` in your `onCreateDialog`

and call `dismissDialog(int)` to dismiss the dialog instead of `dialog.dismiss();`

Comment: Thanks. But `showDialog(int)` and `dismissDialog(int)` is deprecated one. How to solve this problem. I am referred at `developer.android.com` but i have no idea. Can you give me any one example.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
Button button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
Button button2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);

 button1.setOnClickListener(this);
 button2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

implement your Activity by OnClickListener and add unimplemented method which u will get as onClick.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn1:
            //write code
            break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            //write code
            break;
        }
}
```

Do whatever you want to do on click event of button.

Comment: I got error message when i tried to access this line of code `Button button2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);` The Error message is `The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments`

Comment: initialize both the buttons in onCreate of your activity and then set their click listener.clean and build your project.ask when u stuck again