# button within Alert Dialog not clickable

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an Alert Dialog, within the layout for the dialog there is a button that I want to be clickable, however when I use a onclick listener the button still dosn't work.

My Alert Dialog is built up as such.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.distro_editor_popup, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

    txt_Name = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.txt_LinuxName);
    txt_Image = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.txt_ImageName);
    filemanger = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.fileselector); 

    txt_Name.setText(selected_Name);
    txt_Image.setText(selected_Image);

    final String oldName = selected_Name;
    final String oldImage = selected_Image;

    filemanger.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("file/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
        }
    });


    alert.setView(layout);

    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_button_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String name = txt_Name.getText().toString();
            String image = txt_Image.getText().toString();

            // Make sure the user entered a name
            if (name.equals("")) {
                return;
            }

            if (!oldName.equals(name)) {
                // Name was changed so we have to delete the old one from the profiles first!
                profiles.remove(oldName);
            }

            if (!oldImage.equals(image)) {
                // Image name has changed so we rename the mounts and config files
                file_Rename(oldImage + ".mounts", image + ".mounts");
                file_Rename(oldImage + ".config", image + ".config");
            }

            profiles.put(name, image);
            lastSelected = name;

            fillSpinner();
            savePrefs();
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_button_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        }
    });

    alert.show();
```

And then the XML layout for the dialog is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_root"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/layout_root" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_marginTop="8sp" android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/inputLabel_Name"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_LinuxName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/label_Name"
        android:hint="@string/hint_EnterName"
        android:textColor="#FF111111" >

        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_marginTop="8sp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_Image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/launcher_Label_ImageName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_ImageName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fileselector"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/label_Image"
        android:textColor="#FF111111" >

        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fileselector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_ImageName"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="..." />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working, is it crashing, or is nothing happening ?

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer, nothing happens, the alert etc all works fine, however the button 'fileselector' when pressed dosnt do anything

Comment: If you put a toast instead of or before your intent, does that show?

Comment: Nope it dosnt show, looks like the onclick isnt being called?

Comment: If you take `<requestFocus></requestFocus>` lines does the button work? The EditTexts may for some reason be taking away all the focus.

Comment: Removed by no dice still not working..

Comment: Not entirely sure, but a `View.OnClickListener` may not be valid inside a dialog. You could use `alert.setNeutralButton()` and move the file button logic to there. Otherwise, you may need to extend `Dialog` and create you're own custom dialog class to include you're own buttons.

Comment: @DrakeClarris I hope your wrong, however you may well be right, the button works best where it is, the user has to enter a path to a file, or they can click the button to use a file manger and select the file, so it makes sense to be next to the edittext. But if all else fails i will have to change it

Comment: Given the arguments to `onClick` in a `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` does not include a view or a button, but instead the whole dialog and an int to indicate which button, it seems like a good possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling dismiss on the negative button:

```
alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_button_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
          dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

As for the positive, is your `onClick` getting fired? Put Log statements in and see if it is.

Comment: The fileselector button still is not clickable after adding this but thank you I did miss that (although oddly everything else worked without it)

Comment: The positive and negative buttons are working fine, its the extra button 'fileselector' which is within the alert dialogs XML layout thats not working

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess so it is probably wrong, but when you are setting your `onClickListener`, try replacing the line `fileSelector.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener)` with `fileSelector.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener)`

Comment: Have you looked here ? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427925/why-custom-dialog-box-button-is-not-working-in-android